# Exception handling with try and catch

Tags: java, exception

Create  class TestBook, and create test cases to test class Book

Do not handle any exception in this phase, just pass them to the caller method.

Does the above instruction mean my tester class, TestBook should have it's main method "throws ParseException" and when I run my program with an "error" this shouldn't crash instead it should pass the exception to...?

```
  public class TestBook{
       public static Book directory=new Book(); //Book contains an arraylist of dates

     public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
                directory.addApt("01-04-1996","testdate"); 
           //this will create an instance of a  Apt and is in the INCORRECT format.
      }
```

The addApt method from the Book class looks like this:

```
      String[] dates=date.split("-");
        if(dates[0]!=2)
            throw new ParseException("incorrect format day should be in numbers,2);
          if(dates[0]!=3)
            throw new ParseException("incorrect format month should be in letters,2);
          if(dates[0]!=4)
            throw new ParseException("incorrect format year should be in numbers,2);
        Apt newAppt=new Apt=(date,type);
```

When I run this, i get an error message: Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: incorrect format, month should be in letters.

But My question is why this shows up, since I am throwing it, why is it handling it like this? i guess I am confused about the throw(s) vs. try/catch..

Comment: You have declared to throw ParseException from main without handling it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this code does not compile. Did you mean `dates[0].length != 2`? Then it should be `dates[0]`, `dates[1]`, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`throw` throws an `exception`.  The keyword allows you to throw your own custom exceptions.

ALL unhandled exceptions, custom or standard, will cause a run time exception.

Put the code that calls the `addApt` method in a `try/catch` block, and `catch` the `exceptions` that you're `throwing`.

---

Throwing an exception is a great way to get out of returning a value from a method with a non-void return type.  For a very simple example, suppose we have a method called `public int getDaysInMonth(int month)`.  Now, we're going to expect `month` to be 1-12.  And our method has to return an int.  So what do we do when the method is called with an invalid month?

```
int getDaysInMonth(int month) {
    switch(month) {
        //case 1-12
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

So... we can have a case for all of the valid months, that's not a problem.  One solution would be to perhaps return `0`, or `-1` or something that will be an obvious return value.  But we don't actually have to return anything at all.  We can just throw an exception.

```
default:
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Month must be between 1 and 12");
```

Now, we put our calls to `getDaysInMonth(int)` in a `try/catch` block, or if we don't, our program will potentially stop with an illegal argument exception.  But we can put the logic in the `catch` block to deal with how to handle this exception, etc.

I know my example isn't modeled after your situation, but it's a decent example of how to make good use of `throw`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the assignment is to create a class `TestBook` without a `main` method, but with other `static` methods that test the `Book` class. For example, you might have one method that test creating books in the right format, one that test creating books in the wrong format, etc.

Answer (score 0):

No one is catching/handling the exception you threw, so it bubbles all the way to the top and ends up getting printed out. What were you expecting to happen?

`throw` triggers the exception. If you want to handle it yourself, you need to `catch` it somewhere...